# How to show tooltip for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
        $(function(){ 
        $("#plus").tooltip({
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover',
            title : 'test'
        })
        $('#minus').tooltip({
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover',
            title : 'test'
        })
    });    


<button class="btn" type="button" id="plus"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></button
<button class="btn" type="button" id="minus"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></button>
```

i'm write your code isn't show your popup.

anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have done it correctly. First buttons end tag is not closed though.

```
</button
```

Is other bootstrap functionality working (i.e. bootstrap js files included etc.)?

I tested your example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RL2ux/) (switched placement to bottom)